# How to start a Lottie Animation on tap in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, lottie

I want to use a Lottie Animation as a micro interaction in my Flutter App. I want this animation to play when the user taps on it. After reading the documentation of the Lottie Package I know how to add the Animation and how to display it. But I don't understand yet how I can start the animation with a Gesture Detectors onTap property and play it only once.

I tried this by using the forward() method of the Animation Controller but it seems not to work:

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _controller.forward();
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Lottie.asset('assets/test.json', repeat: false, controller: _controller),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          _controller.forward();
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Lottie.asset('assets/test.json',
          repeat: false,
          controller: _controller,
          onLoaded: (composition) {
                _controller
                  ..duration = composition.duration;
              },
          ),
        ),
      )
```